# Regarding List Views and Image Binding in Win UI

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, winui-3, winui

I had a query with regards to Win UI and I was hoping someone could help me out with this. I am relatively new to the framework and I was looking at list views and reused some code that was provided on the Microsoft Documentation. Find attached a modified version of the code in question.

```xml
<ListView
    x:Name="List"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.List}"
    Width="400"
    SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged">
    <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid
                Background="{ThemeResource SystemBaseHighColor}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="Column 1" />
                <TextBlock
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Text="Column 2" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate
            x:Name="TableDataTemplate"
            x:DataType="viewmodels:SampleObject">
            <Grid
                Height="50"
                AutomationProperties.Name="{x:Bind ObjectName}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Text="{x:Bind ObjectName}" />
                <Image
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Source="{x:Bind ObjectPath}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

In this piece of code, I have binded the source of the image to the path I would like it to display. However, if I change the path for the respective object during runtime, it does update the data that is stored in the view model. However, it does not update the image binding. Is there something that I am doing wrong, and how can I make it such that the image automatically updates depending on the value of the path. Is there some method that should be called to update or refresh the list view? Or am I supposed to write the binding code differently?

Many thanks for your time, in advance!

I tried looking at the documentation and reading through most of the properties they have highlighted, but there did not seem to be anything relevant to what I was looking for. I also looked at several threads that could be related to this, but couldn't find anything too relevant, although it is possible I may have overlooked it.

Comment: Show your ViewModel. Most likely you haven't implemented INotifyPropertyChanged interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to your ViewModel.

With the [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/) NuGet package, your ViewModel could be something like this.

```cs
public partial class SampleObject : ObservableObject
{
    // CommunityToolkit.Mvvm's source generator will create 
    // an UI interactive "ObjectName" property for you.
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string objectName = string.Empty;

    // An "ObjectPath" property will be created.
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string objectPath = string.Empty;
}

public partial class ViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    // A "List" property will be created.
    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<SampleObject> list = new();
}
```

You also need to set the `Mode` to `OneWay` when you use `x:Bind`.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I have written some code with the INotifyPropertyChanged in mind, which I will attach in an answer to this post. Could you have a look and let me know if it is written correctly, or if there are any errors? And if I'm not mistaken, I don't need to make any changes to the XAML as it automatically picks up the updated value. Is that correct?

Comment: Set OneWay mode on x:Bind maybe.

Comment: I have done that, although I am not too sure why it still doesn't work :(

Comment: I actually created a sample app for this and it works. `Source="{x:Bind ObjectPath, Mode=OneWay}"` should do the trick. Can you show your code how you are updating the `ObjectPath` on each items in the `List` collection?

Comment: I made a few changes to my project last night, and it started working. I'm not sure what the problem was, unfortunately. It's like you said, it should work with that. I must have written some code incorrectly, resulting in that scenario. Regardless, many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code written by implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged. Kindly let me know if it is correct or not. And would I need to change the binding code in the XAML in any way? Thanks!

```
public partial class ViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private ObservableCollection<SampleObject> list = new();

    public ViewModel()
    {
        // Constructor Logic
    }
}

public partial class SampleObject : ObservableObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string objectName = string.Empty;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string objectPath = string.Empty;

    public SampleObject()
    {
        // Constructor Logic
    }

    public void UpdateObjectPath(String value)
    {
        // Update Object Path Logic
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public string ObjectPath
        {
            get => objectPath;

            set
            {
                if (value != objectPath)
                {
                    ObjectPath = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you use the **CommunityToolkit.Mvvm**, you don't need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, `NotifyPropertyChanged` method or `ObjectPath` property. The source generator will automatically implement those for you.